# ManyToOne Relationship causing Error Could not resolve binding for table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am stuck with an issue in defining my Hibernate entity.
Which is defined as follows:

**Entity Consent:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Consent", schema = "OPTIO")
public class Consent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence-generator")
    @Column(name = "Id" , columnDefinition="unique, NOT NULL")
    private Integer Id;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Date CreatedOnUtc;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="DisclaimerId", referencedColumnName = "Id", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=false)
    private Disclaimer Disclaimer;
```

**Entity Disclaimer:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DISCLAIMER", schema="OPTIO")
public class Disclaimer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence-generator2")
    @Column(name = "Id" , columnDefinition="unique NOT NULL")
    private Integer Id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String Name;
```

The application won't load. The EntitityManagerFactory definition throws an Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\EclipseWorkspace2021-JDK15\optioversion3\src\test\resources\optio_beans_test.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: optio_persistence_unit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve binding for table `Consent`
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:95)
    at com.netsol.optioversion3.test.OPTIOTestDriver.main(OPTIOTestDriver.java:62)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: optio_persistence_unit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve binding for table `Consent`
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve binding for table `Consent`
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.AbstractColumnReferenceQualifier.resolveTableReference(AbstractColumnReferenceQualifier.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.createTableGroupJoin(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:572)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.tree.from.TableGroupJoinProducer.createTableGroupJoin(TableGroupJoinProducer.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.createTableGroupJoin(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:518)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.lambda$generateFetch$0(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.sql.ast.spi.FromClauseAccess.resolveTableGroup(FromClauseAccess.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.generateFetch(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.ToOneAttributeMapping.generateFetch(ToOneAttributeMapping.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.lambda$createFetchableBiConsumer$8(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.lambda$visitFetches$7(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:526)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.visitFetchables(AbstractEntityPersister.java:6412)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.visitFetches(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSqlAstCreationState.visitFetches(LoaderSqlAstCreationState.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.AbstractFetchParent.afterInitialize(AbstractFetchParent.java:30)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityResultImpl.<init>(EntityResultImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntityResultImpl.<init>(EntityResultImpl.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createDomainResult(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1234)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.generateSelect(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.LoaderSelectBuilder.createSelect(LoaderSelectBuilder.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.createLoadPlan(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.prepare(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.prepareLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4467)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4458)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.RuntimeMetamodelsImpl.finishInitialization(RuntimeMetamodelsImpl.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1263)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    ... 16 more
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated:

If I change the `FetchType` to `LAZY` it loads up but fails down stream when inserting `Consent` table entry.
On setting `FetchType` to `LAZY` and removing `@NotTNull` from the `JoinColumn` BUT passing a null `Disclaimer` instance it seems to work fine and the new row gets inserted/created in the underlying Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look the generated statement for table creation:

```
create table consent (id unique, NOT NULL not null, disclaimer_id unique NOT NULL not null, primary key ...)
```

You’ll see `id unique, NOT NULL not null` with two `not null`. The reason for this is that you’re using both `@Id` and `columnDefinition = "unique NOT NULL"` on the primary key column. This causes the above incorrectly produced table creation statement to be generated.

You should remove `columnDefinition = "unique NOT NULL"` part because you don’t need this. You’re already using `@Id` annotation.

This applies to both tables. You should both update `Id` fields in the `Consent` and `Disclaimer` classes.

*Update:*

Consent.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Consent", schema = "OPTIO")
public class Consent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence-generator")
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Integer Id;
    
    //...
}
```

Disclaimer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DISCLAIMER", schema = "OPTIO")
public class Disclaimer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence-generator2")
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Integer Id;
    
    //...
}
```

You can simply add the two lines below into the application.properties file to see the generated SQL statements on the console:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

Comment: Hi @Hulya many thanks. But the problem still exists I cleaned up the Entity ID columns as you suggested. Another question. How do I see the generated statement for table creation ?

Comment: Hi @BrianAntao I added an update for logging and the entities...

Comment: Hi @Hulya -- I have made all the changes you have suggested in both Entity Definitions, But No effect. The problem still persists.Why is it failing with this Exception ?  
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve binding for table `Consent`  Is it failing to add the reference to the Schema to the table perhaps ? In the SQL's generated in the logs it is referring to Insert 0: insert into OPTIO.Consent

Comment: I changed the FetchType to LAZY and get the following exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizer.isInstance(Object)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.persister.entity.EntityPersister.getEntityTuplizer()" is null
 at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.toLoggableString(EntityType.java:514)
 at org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter.toString(EntityPrinter.java:73)
 at org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter.toString(EntityPrinter.java:117)
 ventListener.java:127)
 at `

Comment: @BrianAntao Your question on the post is well prepared, includes required information to regenerate the exception. But it seems unlikely to generate the exception after removing `columnDefinition = "unique NOT NULL"` parts.

Comment: It is possible that there are other causes that lead you to have problems. Pointing only one problem in a question is a good practice on SO. I recommend you to prepare a new question (if you still need) explaining the current situation with all the required parts.

Comment: Hi @Hulya -- all working now -- I just updated the Hibernate libs version to the latest one '<hibernate.version>6.0.0.Alpha7</hibernate.version>` and all started working !!